# How to wait for place ship click event to complete before calling next place ship function in JavaScript Battleship game loop

Tags: javascript

**Problem:** I call playerPlaceShip (from a DOM interaction module) inside a game loop module. This lets the user hover the board, click to place the ship, and finally in the event handler call board.placeShip() (from the gameBoard module). This works in isolation, but when I add another playerPlaceShip call to place an additional ship, it executes immediately before the first ship can be placed by clicking.

**Desired outcome:** A way to wait until the click event from the first function call completes before the next function call begins.

**What I've tried:** Hours of unsuccessfully trying to write and use promises. Hours of reading about promises. Spent a lot of time unsuccessfully trying to rethink how the code is structured. It seems like the click event should be driving the next action, but I don't see how to do that without writing more and more function calls inside the click event handler, which would seem to take control of the game flow away from the game loop module and put it in the DOM interaction module.

Full modules on GitHub: https://github.com/Pete-Fowler/battleship/tree/player-place-ships/src/modules

**Code excerpts:**

```
// In game loop module after creating ships, players, and board objects:

    // Render Board
    renderBoard(p1Board, p1Box);
    renderBoard(p2Board, p2Box);
    
    // Player place ships - lets user hover and click board to place
      playerPlaceShip(p1Board, p1Carrier);
      playerPlaceShip(p1Board, p1Battleship);     // this gets called too soon before click event from the first call completes
    
    
    // In DOM module:
    const clickToPlace = (e, board, ship) => {
      let { x, y } = e.target.dataset;
      x = parseInt(x, 10);
      y = parseInt(y, 10)
      board.place(ship, x, y, axis);
      renderShadow(e, 'place', ship.length);
      removeListeners();
    }
    
    // Main function for player to place ship
    const playerPlaceShip = (board, ship) => {
      const squares = document.querySelectorAll('#p1 .board .square');
      narrative.textContent = `Lead your ${ship.type} into battle. Press X to steer.`;
      
      squares.forEach(square => {
        square.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => renderShadow(e, 'fill', ship.length));
        square.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => renderShadow(e, 'clear', ship.length));
        square.addEventListener('click', (e) => clickToPlace(e, board, ship));
      });
    
      window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        if(e.key === 'x') {
          switchAxis();
          squares.forEach(square => square.classList.remove('hovered'));
          renderShadow(lastCoords, 'fill', ship.length);
        }
      });
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I downloaded your project and tried to run, got this: https://prnt.sc/aN_RXprSorgb

Comment: @PauloFernando - Thanks for looking. That looks like an older version. I'm using webpack and the webpack-dev-server and had forgotten to run npm run build for a while, which is why you saw the older version. You could run it with npm run build, or if you pull from the repo again, I pushed changes including the most recent build, sorry. It looks like this: [screen shot](https://replit.com/@PeteFowler/sandbox#battleship.jpg)

Comment: Hi Pete, I used npm run build and it remained the same, in github your last commit is `Add pseudocode for UIPlayerPlace` 2 days ago

Comment: @PauloFernando - I apologize for making it so difficult. It looks like the problem was I was working on a feature branch and sent the wrong link to main. It is here: https://github.com/Pete-Fowler/battleship/tree/player-place-ships/src/modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to checkout the branch, got a strange error: `invalid path 'src/images/background.jpg:Zone.Identifier'`, maybe because of the colon `:` after `jpg`. So I downloaded the zip.

Otherwise I would have done a pull request, that would be easier for you to merge.

I added logic so that the ship is always inside the board, and created a custom event to trigger after place ship. There are comments, see if this will help you move on.

**game.js**

```
import gameBoard from "./gameBoard";
import player from "./player";
import makeShip from "./ship";
import { p1Box, p2Box, playerPlaceShip, placeShipEventName, AIPlaceShip, renderBoard, UIAttack } from "./DOM";

const startingShipCount = 5;

// SETUP

// Make game boards
const p1Board = gameBoard();
p1Board.init();
const p2Board = gameBoard();
p2Board.init();

// Make players
const p1 = player("Gustav", p1Board, "human");
const p2 = player("Terminator", p2Board, "AI");

// Make p1 ships
const p1Ptb = makeShip("patrolBoat");
const p1Sub = makeShip("sub");
const p1Destroyer = makeShip("destroyer");
const p1Battleship = makeShip("battleship");
const p1Carrier = makeShip("carrier");

// Make AI ships
const p2Ptb = makeShip("patrolBoat");
const p2Sub = makeShip("sub");
const p2Destroyer = makeShip("destroyer");
const p2Battleship = makeShip("battleship");
const p2Carrier = makeShip("carrier");

// Render Board
renderBoard(p1Board, p1Box);
renderBoard(p2Board, p2Box);

// AI place ships
p2Board.place(p2Ptb, 0, 1, "y");
p2Board.place(p2Sub, 2, 6, "y");
p2Board.place(p2Destroyer, 4, 2, "y");
p2Board.place(p2Battleship, 6, 6, "y");
p2Board.place(p2Carrier, 8, 4, "y");

renderBoard(p1Board, p1Box);
renderBoard(p2Board, p2Box);

//################################################
//###################### HANDLE placeShipPhase
//################################################
let countShipsPlaced = 0;
const handlePlaceShipPhase = () => {
  countShipsPlaced++;

  if (countShipsPlaced == startingShipCount) {
    startGame();
  } else {
    playerPlaceShip(p1Board, p1Carrier);
  }
};

//######################################################
//####### LISTENING to the custom event Place Ship
//######################################################
window.addEventListener(placeShipEventName, handlePlaceShipPhase);

// Player places ships
playerPlaceShip(p1Board, p1Carrier);

const startGame = () => {
  alert("Game started, battle!");
};

// MAIN GAME LOOP - will need loop

// Player attack
// UIAttack(p2Board);

// AI attack

// Gameover - after exit loop

// The game loop should set up a new game by creating Players and Gameboards.
// For now just populate each Gameboard with predetermined coordinates. You can
// implement a system for allowing players to place their ships later.
// The game loop should step through the game turn by turn using only methods
// from other objects. If at any point you are tempted to write a new function
// inside the game loop, step back and figure out which class or module that
// function should belong to.
// Create conditions so that the game ends once one players ships have all
// been sunk. This function is appropriate for the Game module.
```

**DOM.js**

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-expressions */

const p1Box = document.querySelector("#p1");
const p2Box = document.querySelector("#p2");
const narrative = document.querySelector("#narrative");

let axis = "y"; // used to render shadow in playerPlaceShip
let selectedSquares = [];
let lastCoords;
const boardSize = 10;

//save the current ship to be used in the "x" key event listender
let currentShip;

//moved outside of the placeship otherwise will add duplicated events
window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.key.toLocaleLowerCase() === "x") {
    const squares = document.querySelectorAll("#p1 .board .square");
    switchAxis();
    squares.forEach((square) => square.classList.remove("hovered"));
    renderShadow(lastCoords, "fill", currentShip.length);
  }
});

//#############################################
//##### CREATING the custom event Place Ship
//#############################################
const placeShipEventName = "playerplaceship";
const placeShipEvent = new Event(placeShipEventName);

// Helper functions for playerPlaceShip
const switchAxis = () => {
  axis === "x" ? (axis = "y") : (axis = "x");
};

const renderShadow = (e, fill, length) => {
  let { x, y } = e.target.dataset;
  x = parseInt(x, 10);
  y = parseInt(y, 10);

  selectedSquares = [];

  let count = countOfSquaresOutOfBoard(x, y, length);

  //#### LOGIC TO RENDER SHIP ALWAYS INSIDE BOARD
  for (let i = -count; i < length - count; i++) {
    setSelectedSquares(x, y, i);
  }

  for (const el of selectedSquares) {
    fill === "fill" ? el.classList.add("hovered") : el.classList.remove("hovered");
    if (fill === "place") {
      el.classList.add("placed");
    }
  }
  lastCoords = e;
};

const removeListeners = () => {
  const squares = document.querySelectorAll("#p1 .board .square");
  squares.forEach((square) => {
    square.replaceWith(square.cloneNode());
  });
};

const clickToPlace = (shipSquare, board, ship) => {
  let { x, y } = shipSquare.dataset;
  x = parseInt(x, 10);
  y = parseInt(y, 10);
  board.place(ship, x, y, axis);
  renderShadow(lastCoords, "place", ship.length);
  removeListeners();

  //#######################################################
  //############# TRIGGERING the custom event place ship
  //#########################################################
  window.dispatchEvent(placeShipEvent);

  console.log(board.getMap());
};

// Main function for player to place ship
const playerPlaceShip = (board, ship) => {
  currentShip = ship;

  const squares = document.querySelectorAll("#p1 .board .square");
  narrative.textContent = `Lead your ${ship.type} into battle. Press X to steer.`;

  squares.forEach((square) => {
    square.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => renderShadow(e, "fill", ship.length));
    square.addEventListener("mouseout", (e) => renderShadow(e, "clear", ship.length));
    square.addEventListener("click", (e) => clickToPlace(selectedSquares[0], board, ship));
  });
};

const countOfSquaresOutOfBoard = (x, y, length) => {
  let count = 0;

  if (axis === "x") {
    count = x + length - boardSize;
  }

  if (axis === "y") {
    count = y + length - boardSize;
  }

  return count < 0 ? 0 : count;
};

const setSelectedSquares = (x, y, i) => {
  if (axis === "x") {
    selectedSquares.push(document.querySelector(`#p1 .square[data-x="${x + i}"][data-y="${y}"]`));
  } else {
    selectedSquares.push(document.querySelector(`#p1 .square[data-x="${x}"][data-y="${y + i}"]`));
  }
};

// Lets AI place ship
const AIPlaceShip = (board) => {};

const renderBoard = (board, box) => {
  // Clear old content prior to re-render if needed
  let grid = document.querySelector(`#${box.id} .board`);
  if (grid) {
    grid.textContent = "";
  } else {
    grid = document.createElement("div");
    grid.className = "board";
  }
  // Individual squares on board
  for (let i = 0; i <= 9; i += 1) {
    for (let j = 9; j >= 0; j -= 1) {
      const square = document.createElement("div");
      square.className = "square";
      square.dataset.x = i;
      square.dataset.y = j;
      grid.append(square);
    }
  }
  box.append(grid);
};

// Player attack phase - sends x, y from clicked square to board.incoming()
const attackCallback = (e, board) => {
  const { x, y } = e.target.dataset;
  board.incoming(x, y);
  const squares = document.querySelectorAll("#p2 .square");
  squares.forEach((el) => {
    el.removeEventListener("click", attackCallback);
    el.classList.remove("hoverable");
  });
  console.log(board.getMap());
};

// Player attack phase - adds click event listener and hover effect
const UIAttack = (board) => {
  const squares = document.querySelectorAll("#p2 .square");
  squares.forEach((el) => {
    el.addEventListener("click", (e) => attackCallback(e, board));
    el.classList.add("hoverable");
  });
  narrative.textContent = "Click to fire on the enemy fleet";
};

export { p1Box, p2Box, placeShipEventName, playerPlaceShip, AIPlaceShip, renderBoard, UIAttack };
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check this out later today, but it looks like just the kind of thing I was not aware of that could make it work.